# Cannot connect to the process running Strapi from URL on Google App Engine

Tags: postgresql, docker, google-app-engine, strapi

After deploying Strapi to Google App Engine, I can see it running due to the following log messages:

```
2022-09-28 04:38:51 default[20220928t143613]  ┌────────────────────┬──────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
2022-09-28 04:38:51 default[20220928t143613]  │ Time               │ Wed Sep 28 2022 04:38:51 GMT+0000 (Coordinated … │
2022-09-28 04:38:51 default[20220928t143613]  │ Launched in        │ 4328 ms                                          │
2022-09-28 04:38:51 default[20220928t143613]  │ Environment        │ production                                       │
2022-09-28 04:38:51 default[20220928t143613]  │ Process PID        │ 11                                               │
2022-09-28 04:38:51 default[20220928t143613]  │ Version            │ 4.3.9 (node v16.17.0)                            │
2022-09-28 04:38:51 default[20220928t143613]  │ Edition            │ Community                                        │
2022-09-28 04:38:51 default[20220928t143613]  └────────────────────┴──────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
2022-09-28 04:38:51 default[20220928t143613]   Actions available
2022-09-28 04:38:51 default[20220928t143613]  Welcome back!
2022-09-28 04:38:51 default[20220928t143613]  To manage your project , go to the administration panel at:
2022-09-28 04:38:51 default[20220928t143613]  http://0.0.0.0:8081/admin
2022-09-28 04:38:51 default[20220928t143613]  To access the server ⚡️, go to:
2022-09-28 04:38:51 default[20220928t143613]  http://0.0.0.0:8081
```

I also have Cron Jobs running successfully and appearing in the log messages:

```
2022-09-28 05:08:10 default[20220928t150116]  CRON_JOB_PRODUCT_IMPORT_START
2022-09-28 05:08:10 default[20220928t150116]  CRON_JOB_PRODUCT_IMPORT_END
```

After the deployment, I attempt to launch the website using `gcloud app browse` and the request times out eventually with a 404 Not Found. I see no activity in the log messages for the requests to the URL.

---

Other useful information:

**app.yaml**

```
runtime: nodejs16

instance_class: B1

basic_scaling:
  idle_timeout: 5m
  max_instances: 1

build_env_variables:
  API_HOST: project-id.uc.r.appspot.com
  NODE_ENV: 'production'

env_variables:
  ADMIN_JWT_SECRET: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXX'
  API_TOKEN_SALT: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXX'
  APP_KEYS: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXX'
  DATABASE_HOST: '/cloudsql/project-id:us-central1:database-id'
  DATABASE_PORT: '5432'
  DATABASE_NAME: 'database-id'
  DATABASE_USERNAME: 'postgres'
  DATABASE_PASSWORD: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXX'
  DATABASE_SSL: 'false'
  HOST: '0.0.0.0'
  JWT_SECRET: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXX'
  NODE_ENV: 'production'
  PORT: '1337'

beta_settings:
  cloud_sql_instances: 'project-id:us-central1:database-id'
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:16

# Installing libvips-dev for sharp Compatability
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install libvips-dev -y

# Node Environment (development/production)
ARG NODE_ENV=development
ENV NODE_ENV=${NODE_ENV}
RUN echo "NODE_ENV: $NODE_ENV"

ARG API_HOST=todo
ENV API_HOST=${API_HOST}
RUN echo "API_HOST: $API_HOST"

# Root directory
WORKDIR /opt/
COPY ./ .
ENV PATH /opt/node_modules/.bin:$PATH
RUN yarn config set network-timeout 600000 -g && yarn ci

WORKDIR /opt/app
RUN yarn build

EXPOSE 1337
CMD ["yarn", "start"]
```

I can see the service is starting multiple times in the logs, whilst `max_instances` is set to 1. Is there a /health status that could be failing?

Answer (score 0):

I got to the end of writing this question and noticed something in the logs:

```
No entrypoint specified, using default entrypoint: /serve
```

This leads me to someone's comment about exposing their Nodejs application on port 8080. I open the application on port 8080 and now Strapi is loading.